# Как менять местами div'ы в зависимости от ширины окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как менять местами div'ы в зависимости от ширины окна?
Имеем два дива. `#div1` и `#div2`

Если ширина окна больше 976, то менять местами, если ширина меньше, то опять же менять местами назад.

Comment: Адаптивная верстка для вас не существует?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex) и [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#container div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
@media (min-width: 976px) {
  #red {
    order: 2;
  }
  #green {
    order: 1;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 976px) {
  #red {
    order: 1;
  }
  #green {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="red">Red</div>
  <div id="green">Green</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, используя [JQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($( window ).width() > 976)
    $("#div1").insertBefore($("#div2"));   
  else
    $("#div2").insertBefore($("#div1"));   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

на css3:

но [плохо работает с IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать media-запрос.

Только для вертикальных (блоки рядом):

1. float - поменять left и right местами.
2. float - поменять с left на right.
3. inline-block - поменять у контейнера direction с ltr на rtl. Не забыть вернуть у потомков.

Для любых:

4. flex - использовать reverse.
5. flex - использовать order.
6. position:relative и сдвиги (не рекомендуется).

Думаю, достаточно способов. Хотя, подозреваю, что можно ещё что-то придумать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добиться поддержки IE 9+ с такой версткой:

```css
.test {
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
}
.a,
.b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #div1 {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }
  #div2 {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот ссылка на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2pm6mzv/3/). Чтобы посмотреть работу `@media` в здешнем сниппете нажмите на кнопку "на всю страницу" и сравните результат.

`table-footer-group` и `table-header-group` позволяют менять блоки местами, но это работает только внутри элемента с `display: table` и наличие дочерних блоков (в примере это `.a` и `.b`) обязательно.